# How to generate Joomla login token from outside Joomla

Tags: wordpress, authentication, joomla, token, csrf

Here's the context. I have a Joomla Backend with tons of custom code in a very old Joomla 1.X version. Everything is still surprisingly holding up well. The site owner wants a new front facing website and his company chose WordPress. Website was built, now we want to add a log in form to the Joomla backend from a WP page.

Here's what worked:

1. Go to Joomla login page (domain.com/administrator)
2. Copy the HTML form (including hidden input with token)
3. Paste the HTML and adjust the action attribute of the form
4. Went to the WP page (domain.com/wordpressFolder/page, entered credentials and it works perfectly!

Obviously these tokens can only be used once. Added a shortcode in WP that gets the form from Joomla and "extract" the token and returns it to the page.

```
  function st_login_form( $atts ) {
  $joomla = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/administrator/index.php');
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($joomla);
  $inputs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input');
  $token = $inputs[5]->attributes[1]->nodeValue;

  $html = '<form action="https://www.example.com/administrator/index.php" method="post" name="login" id="form-login" style="clear: both;">
    <p id="form-login-username">
    <label for="modlgn_username">Username</label>
    <input name="username" id="modlgn_username" type="text" class="inputbox" size="15">
    </p>

    <p id="form-login-password">
    <label for="modlgn_passwd">Password</label>
    <input name="passwd" id="modlgn_passwd" type="text" class="inputbox" size="15">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Connexion" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_login">
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="'.$token.'" value="1">
    </form>';

    return $html;
  }
```

The code behaves has expected and inspecting the form on the WP page with injected token looks fine, however when logging in it gives me an invalid token error.

I don't quite understand why it works when copy pasting but not when I retrieve the token from PHP. Any clue or potential solutions?

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Found my first mistake. The GET is done over HTTP while the POST is sent over HTTPS. Obviously, CSRF token are domain-signed.

Now it simply redirects me to the login page but I'm not logged in.

Comment: This is not a complete answer to the problem.  I recommend that you edit your question to include this progress and ask for help with the remaining issue.  Are you trying to do the very thing that the CSRF token is designed to prevent?  Is this an XY problem?